# Could not find RippleDrawable and i'm not using Image just simple TextView

Tags: android, json, android-layout, listview

i want  to load data from PHP jason file in a webhost in a listView   all  codes is all rights  , but when i'm dbg  i get this error

```
 E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.hasOverlappingRendering
```